# Setting read access using permissions.acl

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Looking at the hyperledger composer tutorials, it seems access control can be implemented for transactions, but not reading from asset registries.

Is there a way to prevent some participants from reading certain assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the reverse -- the ACLs are currently *all* about participants attempting to perform operations on assets.

Please refer to the docs for details:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/acl_language.html

Comment: Thanks Dan Selman - good to see this point being addressed so simply in hyperledger composer.

Comment: All the ACLs seem to be disabled when I run hyperledger fabric with a business network definition locally, with all access to all resources enabled by default. Seems to be a similar situation reported here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082228/why-does-hyperledger-composer-acl-file-not-take-effect